# clone img src to use as a div background via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, web

I'm having trouble trying to clone the string of a URL in the src= value of an . 
I'm trying to define the string as a variable so that I can append the "background-image" css value with said variable.
...
Taking an  and using it as a background-image in a

I'm doing so in a $(window).load event since I think the  has to be rendered in the DOM in order for it's URL to be present.
However, nothing seems to be working. I can alert(imgURL); but fail to plug it into the 's background.

Here's what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var imgURL = $('.thumbnail img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src');
  });
  $('.fullsize').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgURL + ')');
  });

});
```

```css
.fullsize {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.thumbnail img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="fullsize"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://twiki.org/p/pub/Plugins/GnuPlotPlugin/BlueWhaleSample.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="fullsize"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://twiki.org/p/pub/Plugins/GnuPlotPlugin/RosenbrockFunctionSample.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$(window).load(` use `$(document).ready(function()...` this will ensure that DOM is ready and iterate all `.fullsize` and find the image inside thumbnail to replace the background. See below script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fullsize').each(function() {
    var imgURL = $(this).next('.thumbnail').find('img').attr('src');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgURL + ')');
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hob6sLb/)**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I was on the right track. I was missing the .find() method, therefor it wouldn't iterate through each class.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `imgURL` refers to a jQuery object containing all the `.thumbnail img` elements.

Instead what you can do is use the .css() method as below to find the `src` of the `img` element in the next sibling of the current `fullsize` element.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.fullsize').css('background-image', function() {
    return 'url(' + $(this).next().find('img').attr('src') + ')'
  });

});
```

```css
.fullsize {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.thumbnail img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="fullsize"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://twiki.org/p/pub/Plugins/GnuPlotPlugin/BlueWhaleSample.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="fullsize"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://twiki.org/p/pub/Plugins/GnuPlotPlugin/RosenbrockFunctionSample.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First - I would wrap your each div with a classname given to it as below:

```
<div class="mainParent">
  <div class="fullsize"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://twiki.org/p/pub/Plugins/GnuPlotPlugin/BlueWhaleSample.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainParent">
  <div class="fullsize"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://twiki.org/p/pub/Plugins/GnuPlotPlugin/RosenbrockFunctionSample.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and then I would prefer to do it on document.ready as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each('.mainParent',function(){
       $(this).find('.fullsize').css('background-image',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
  });
});
```